# How to find the average of multiple rows and store the value in a new dataframe? in python

Tags: python, average

Instruction: Convert each row as a quarter. Meaning 1000 rows would equate to 250 years. Start with 3rd quarter in 1947.

I have this dataset. Each row corresponds to a data per month. I have to convert this data by quarter. So first, I have to get the average of the first 4 rows and store it as 1947 Q3 or 3rd Quarter and same goes for the following rows. How do I code that in python?
Sample view of the dataset:

| nr | index | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 392.830017 |
| 1 | 2.0 | 392.512085 |
| 2 | 3.0 | 397.305908 |
| 3 | 4.0 | 398.011322 |
| 4 | 5.0 | 400.490204 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 995 | 996.0 | 801.340027 |
| 996 | 997.0 | 806.969971 |
| 997 | 998.0 | 808.380005 |
| 998 | 999.0 | 809.559998 |

The new dataframe should look like this

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1947 Q3 | 454.21 |
| 1947 Q4 | 2748.27 |
| 1948 Q1 | 7482.94 |
| 1948 Q2 | 4878.242 |
| 1948 Q3 | 436.24 |
| 1948 Q4 | 9284.432 |
| 1949 Q1 | 6274.43 |
| 1949 Q2 | 872 |
| 1949 Q3 | 2874.42 |
| 1949 Q4 | 9829.427 |
| ... | ... |
| 2010 Q4 | 8294.47 |

The data inside `value` is just an example.

Comment: Please post your data as tables next time. I'll edit your post :)

Comment: My apologies. I am very new here and so I am still learning how to do this. Thank you @tolik1518 for your edit. Next time, I'll format my questions like this. I appreciate your effort!